# How to connect USB Charger outlet

Tags: receptacle

I am trying to replace my old outlet that could be operated by a switch on a wall with new one that have USB Charger build in. I've bought [TopGreener TU2154A](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IAZIU5Y).

When I was removing old one I've noticed it has to 2 hot wires (red and orange) connected to 2 screws on one side that are separated and one neutral (grey).

How can I connect it to this new outlet that only has 3 screws of hot, neutral and ground?

Comment: Is the tab between the two hot screws broken off (removed) on your old outlet? If so, it's half switched and you need to decide if you want the entire outlet (and usb) switched or always on.

Comment: yes the tab is broken. I would be ok with it always on.

Comment: Is this in North America?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a volt meter to find out which of the two hots is switched and which is not.

Use a wire nut to cap the one you don't want to use, and push it back into the box.

Install the usb outlet per its instructions.  If you don't have a ground wire to connect to it, hopefully the outlet box itself is metal and grounded.  If not, then you probably don't need to worry about grounding the usb outlet.